# Unable to pull new image with AKS and ACR

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, acr

I'm suddenly having issues pulling the latest image from Azure container registry with AKS (which previously worked fine.

If I run

```
kubectl describe pod <podid> I get:


Failed to pull image <image>: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get <image>: unauthorized: authentication required
```

I've tried logging into the ACR manually and it's all working correctly - the new images have pushed correctly and I can pull them manually.

Moreover I've tried:

```
az aks update -g MyResourceGroup -n MyManagedCluster --attach-acr acrName
```

Which succeeds (no errors, there is an output propagation being successful) but it still doesn't work.

I've tried updating the credentials with:

```
az aks update-credentials --resource-group <group>--name <aks name>--reset-service-principal --service-principal <sp id> --client-secret <client-secret>
```

Which spits out a rather weird message:

```
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 6e84754a-821d-4a39-a0df-7ab9ba21973f. 
Unable to get log analytics workspace info. Resource ID: 
/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourcegroups/defaultresourcegroup- 
weu/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/defaultworkspace- 
d259e6ea-8230-4cb0-a7a8-7f0df6c7ef18-weu. Details: autorest/azure: Service 
returned an error. Status=404 Code="ResourceGroupNotFound" 
Message="Resource group 'defaultresourcegroup-weu' could not be found.". For 
more details about how to create and use log analytics workspace,  please 
refer to: https://aka.ms/new-log-analytics
```

I tried creating a new log analytics workspace and the error above persisted.

I've also tried steps from:

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication#service-principal)

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639280/kubernetes-cannot-pull-image-from-private-docker-image-repository)

[As well as this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574059/failed-to-pull-image-xx-azurecr-io-xxlatest-rpc-error-code-unknown-desc)

Besides the the posts above, I've gone through many tutorials and Microsoft pages to try fix the problem.

I've tried creating a new service principal and assigning it the appropriate roles but the error still persists.
I've also dabbled with creating new secrets and had no success.

My pods that don't need new images are all running as expected.
If I look at my app registrations (under azure active directory) they were all created a year ago - so I'm concerned something expired and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The advice is that use the ACR resource Id is better. And the error when you update the service principal shows the resource group is not found. So do you check if the group is right? And do you try to reset the service principal credential of the AKS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this working by disabling the Log Analytics addon using:

`az aks disable-addons -a monitoring -n <AKSName> -g <ResourceGroupName>`

As per one of the error messages I posted, it seems my log analytics was just causing things to fall apart (not sure *why* though) so disabled it for the time being and was able to update creds with

`az aks update-credentials --resource-group <group>--name <aks name>--reset-service-principal --service-principal <sp id> --client-secret <client-secret>`

Comment: Amazing, thank you. We have tried everything else to no avail.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

there are two ways to get this sorted

1. Map the ACR to AKS

---

```
CLIENT_ID=$(az aks show --resource-group $AKS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name 
$AKS_CLUSTER_NAME --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION_ID --query "servicePrincipalProfile.clientId" --output tsv)

ACR_ID=$(az acr show --name $ACR_NAME --resource-group $ACR_RESOURCE_GROUP --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION_ID --query "id" --output tsv)

az role assignment create --assignee $CLIENT_ID --role Reader --scope $ACR_ID
```

---

other way is to add the Image pull secret, which will be of type kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson

this can be done by -

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

---

Then you can refer this secret as imagePullSecret in the deployment files and the authentication error shall not be there

Comment: Adding the imagepullsecret worked - however the first method still does not work- even though the command seemed to run correctly (still throwing the same error).  I'm really curious to know why this is the case

Comment: did you mention the subscription ID there , along with the commands I shared !!

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean - in the initial command I ran or in the response I got back?

Comment: I just edited it in the answer, added subscription ID there

Comment: does the subscription of ACR and AKS match at azure or are they different ?

Comment: They both match, re-running the commands with the subscription id ran as expected but the image still doesn't pull

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201094/discussion-between-jpegasus-and-tushar-mahajan).